# Why does torch transpose return a non-contiguous tensor but the equivalent view operation returns a contiguous one?

Tags: python, pytorch

Both `torch.Tensor.view()` and `torch.tensor.transpose()` can transpose a 2 dimensional tensor, e.g.

```
a = torch.arange(8).reshape(2, 4)
a.t().is_contiguous() # False
a.view(4,2).is_contiguous() # True
```

But exchanging the dimensions with `.view()` results in a contiguous tensor while using `.t()` results in a non-contiguous one. It's clearly somehow possible to transpose while retaining contiguity, though I don't really understand how, but my main question is: why is this behavior different for these two functions?

The documentation for `view` says that the "returned tensor shares the same data" and for `transpose` that the "resulting `out` tensor shares its underlying storage with the `input` tensor" so I naively expect the contiguity status of the outputs to be the same for both functions, but perhaps "sharing the same data" and "sharing underlying storage" are two different things?

Edit: It did not occur to me that there is a way to reshape this tensor into 4,2 that is *not* tansposing lol. Thanks to the author of the accepted answer for pointing out that a.t() != a.view(dim1, dim0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `view(4, 2)` you are not transposing the tensor, you are simply reshaping it.

Original tensor:

```py
t = torch.tensor([[1, 2],
                  [3, 4],
                  [5, 6],
                  [7, 8]])
```

`t.transpose()` returns:

```
torch.tensor([[1, 3, 5, 7],
              [2, 4, 6, 8]])
```

`t.view(4, 2)` returns:

```
t.tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4],
          [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```